# PDO error code always 00000 even when there is an error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I m running PHP 7.2.16

Not sure when started, PDO errorCode() or errorInfo()[0] now always shows 00000 even there is an error

```
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', 'pwd');
$sth = $pdo->prepare('select now() and this is a bad SQL where a - b from c');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll();
$err = $sth->errorInfo();
echo $sth->errorCode();
print_r($row);
print_r($err);
```

And here is the result:

```
00000Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a bad SQL where a - b from c' at line 1
)
```

However, I just did a new test, by delete `$sth->fetchAll()` or get error before this line, it shows correctly:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a bad SQL where a - b from c' at line 1
)
```

OK - the solution is that:

> > get the error code immediately after `execute()` and before any fetch

Comment: What is 'one' / 'other'? I only see one code. Have you checked `$pdo` for an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code with PHP 7.1.23:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$sth = $pdo->prepare('select now() and this is a bad SQL where a - b from c');
if ($sth === false) {
  echo "error on prepare()\n";
  print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
}
if ($sth->execute() === false) {
  echo "error on execute()\n";
  print_r($sth->errorInfo());
}
```

Output:

```
error on execute()
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a bad SQL where a - b from c' at line 1
)
```

Then I tested the same code, except after disabling emulated prepare:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Output:

```
error on prepare()
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a bad SQL where a - b from c' at line 1
)

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean
```

Moral of the story:

- When using emulated prepared statements, `prepare()` is a no-op, and the error is delayed until `execute()`. I recommend disabling emulated prepare, unless you use a database that doesn't support prepared statements (I don't know of any current version of any RDBMS product that can't do real prepared statements).
- When checking for an error on prepare(), use `$pdo->errorInfo()`.
- When checking for an error on execute(), use `$stmt->errorInfo()`.

Comment: Thanks. You got error because you run the error check before fetchAll etc :) Could you re-test with fetchAll before errorInfo() ?

Comment: It makes no sense to fetchAll() from a query that has failed. You should check for errors immediately after prepare() or execute(). If you disable emulated prepare, you can't even attempt the fetchAll(), because `$sth` will be **false** and you can't call a method from that.

Comment: Yeah. I double check SIDU, which is checking Error before fetch.  Thanks